# Python BeautifulSoup - How to crawl links <a> inside values in <td>

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm learning web scraping and am trying to web crawl data from the below link. Is there a way for me to crawl the link from each of the td as well?

The website link: http://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/programmes/

Here's what I did so far.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/programmes/"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

table_list = []
rows = soup.find_all('tr')

# For every row in the table, find each cell element and add it to the list
for row in rows:
    row_td = row.find_all('td')
    row_cells = str(row_td)
    row_cleantext = BeautifulSoup(row_cells, "lxml").get_text()
    table_list.append((row_cleantext))

print(table_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/programmes/"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
main_data=soup.find_all("td")
```

You can find `main_data` and iterate over that so you will get specific `td` tag and now find `a` and use `.get` for `href` extraction and if any Attribute is not present so you can use `try-except` to handle exceptions

```
for data in main_data:
    try:
        link=data.find("a").get("href")
        print(link)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

For Understing only:

```
main_data=soup.find_all("td")
for data in main_data:
    try:
        link=data.find("a")
        print(link.text)
        print(link.get("href"))
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
H60C
https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/advanced-electronic-and-electrical-engineering-msc/
H60A
https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/advanced-electronic-and-electrical-engineering-msc/

..
```

For creating table you can use `pandas` module

```
main_data=soup.find_all("td")
dict1={}
for data in main_data:
    try:
        link=data.find("a")
        dict1[link.text]=link.get("href")
    except AttributeError:
        pass
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(dict1.items(),columns=["Text","Link"])
```

Output:

```
    Text    Link
0   H60C    https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/cou...
1   H60A    https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/cou...
2   I4U2    https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/cou...
..
```

Getting table from website

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_html("http://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/programmes/")
df=data[0]
df
```

Output

```
Postgraduate degree programmes  Part-time(2 year)   Full-time(1 year)
0   Advanced Electronic and Electrical Engineering  H60C    H60A
1   Artificial Intelligence I4U2    I4U1
.....
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, would it be possible for you to teach me on how to put them all together on a  single df table?

I'm trying to put everything together like the table in the webpages and added 2 more columns that show the link to the program code. So I will then ends up with 5 column: [Postgraduate degree programmes, Part-time Code, Full-time code, Part-time URL, Full-time URL]

Comment: you want to append to a list or create specific table with respective link?

Comment: I want a table that consists of all of the information.. is that possible?